# picking a number of random elements from variable in R

Tags: r

I am a biologist and fairly new to R, so I appreciate any help!
I have the following problem:
I have several data frames that all share the variable "a".
However, the variable differs in length between the data frames. 
What I want to do is to get an exact number (let's say 1000) of random values out of variable "a") for each data frame and create new data frames with these values. 
Maybe it is very easy and I am just too inexperienced to know how to solve this.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Have a look at `?sample`

Comment: You can place the datasets in a `list` i.e. `lst <- list(dat1, dat2, ...datN);  res <- sapply(lst, function(x)  sample(x[['a']], 1000, replace = FALSE))` and write it back

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's what you're looking for?

```
# example data frames: ten thousand values in range 100 to 200
a1 <- sample(x =  100:200,
             size = 10000,
             replace = T)
df1 <- data.frame(a = a1)

# example data frames: ten thousand values in range 800 to 900
a2 <- sample(x =  800:900,
             size = 10000,
             replace = T)
df2 <- data.frame(a = a2)

# get 1000 random entries of every data frame
x <- sample(df1$a, size = 1000)
y <- sample(df2$a, size = 1000)

# make a new data frame out of the values gathered
df <- data.frame(a = x, b = y)
```

Comment: thanks that looks like something that will be useful ! I will report if it worked !